# how do I convert image format from jpeg to png using gm for node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I want to convert to png since it's a pixelated thumbnail with big blocks of color and don't want to waste filesize or get any compression artifiacts with jpeg.

```
gm(inPath).autoOrient().thumbnail('200','200^').gravity('Center').extent(200,200).scale('10%').scale('1000%').write(outPath, function(err, results){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the outPath end with `.png`.